# Counrdown timer with service not working in the fragment

Tags: android, service, countdown

I wanna implement a Countdown timer with updating TextView and a service so the counting can keep going if the app is in background, foreground or even fully closed.

I examined these codes in a simple project and they worked very well

Service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final Integer[] timeRemaining = {intent.getIntExtra("TimeValue", 0)};

        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          Intent intent1local = new Intent();
                                          intent1local.setAction("Counter");
                                          timeRemaining[0]--;
                                          if (timeRemaining[0] <= 0) {
                                              timer.cancel();
                                          }
                                          intent1local.putExtra("TimeRemaining", timeRemaining[0]);
                                          sendBroadcast(intent1local);
                                      }
                                  },
                0, 1000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{FOREGROUND_SERVICE},
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("Counter");
        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Integer integerTime = intent.getIntExtra("TimeRemaining",
                        0);
                textView.setText(integerTime.toString());
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    public void startButton(View view) {
        Intent intentService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        Integer integerTimeSet =
                Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        intentService.putExtra("TimeValue", integerTimeSet);
        startService(intentService);
    }
}
```

But when i implement these codes in an app with fragments (Service codes are in a seperate service class and i put MainActivity codes in a fragment), if you close the app, everything will gone off and you will get an error.

Please help me

I need your detailed advices.

Comment: can you provide the details of error which were you getting in log?

Comment: To be honest, I am using physical emulator and haven't been working with Log. If I want to explain, when the app is in foreground or background, everything is ok but when the timer is running and you decide to close the app, it gives a massage that "your app keeps stopping" and everything goes off

Comment: sorry! but without knowing the exact error it's hard to find what's the causing problem i will suggest that run your app in debugging mode and also check the logcat in Android Studio so you can find the exception.

Comment: ViewRootImpl@807e51b[MainActivity]  28937 / 28937

Comment: This my logcat. Can you help me?

Comment: you should provide whole stacktrace of exception thrown by your application. edit your question with stacktrace shown in your logcat in red coloured text.